# Retrieve Date Added To Library From ALAsset?

Tags: ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary, alasset

Is there any way to retrieve the date an image or video was added to a device's photo library from an ALAsset object? If the image's metadata contains a "created_at" date, ALAssetPropertyDate uses this date instead, and there doesn't seem to be any way to get the actual date the photo was added to the device.

Answer (score 0):

`ALAssetPropertyDate` returns the date/time the image was saved.

Please use `NSDateFormatter` and try it.

```
NSDate *date = [result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss ZZZ"];
NSString *stringDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@", stringDate);
```

or try this

```
ALAssetRepresentation *assetRep = [result defaultRepresentation];
NSDictionary *dictionaryOfMetaData = [assetRep metadata];
NSLog(@"dictionary:%@ \n \ date:%@ \n \ StringDate:%@", [[dictionaryOfMetaData valueForKey:@"{TIFF}"] valueForKey:@"DateTime"], date, stringDate);
```